# Loading image and Invert colors with SDL_Image

Tags: c++, colors, sdl-2, sdl-image

I am currently loading an image using SDL_Image (SDL2) and put that in a texture.
Significative lines of C++ my code, using "source" as a temp SDL_Surface for other reasons, are:

```
SDL_Surface* source;
SDL_Surface* target;
//Use SDL_CreateRGBSurface to initialize target
SDL_Rect offset;
//valorize the offset
source = IMG_Load(pathOfTheImage);
if (source != nullptr)
{
      SDL_BlitScaled(source, &offset, target, NULL);
}
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, target->w, target->h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, target->pixels);
SDL_FreeSurface(source);
```

So far, so good.
I would like to load the image and, based on a variable, invert colors.
By invert colors, I mean to change black in white, white in black...
Something like

```
red = 255 -red;
green = 255 - green;
blue = 255 - blue;
```

Note: My purpose is **not** invert colors such as red channel values becomes blue channel, switching GL_RBGA to GL_BGRA.

I found this solutions on the internet:

- Change every pixel with loops like [this answer](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/346174-inverting-colors-of-a-sdl_surface/3263743/)
- Do the same thing applying a shader.

There is a way to accomplish this by adding just another SDL call (nor the for loop over all the pixels, neither the shader)? The loop seems that would slower the program a lot.

I am dreaming something like `SDL_SwapColors(source)` or any other elegant solutions :) Thank you in advance for any tip.

Comment: Use a shader, that acts automatically on each pixel (if my knowledge is right). And I think it should be `256 - blue` and not `255 - blue`.

Comment: RGBA texture lookup values will be normalized in the shader when using the typical `texture()` sampler, so if you fetch `vec4 t = texture(...)`, you will subtract each component from `1.0`, i.e., `vec4 inv = vec4(vec3(1.0) - vec3(t), t.a);`

Comment: @BrettHale you are talking about a shader implementation, right?